# Algorithm for sorting an array using another array named gaps[]

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is a piece of code from a program. This code tends to sort the array 
horses whose size is n. How does the array gap help in sorting the array horses?

```
int gaps[]={701,301,132,57,23,10,4,1};
for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
for (i = gaps[k]; i < n; ++i) 
{
temp = horses[i];
for (j = i; j >= gaps[k] && horses[j-gaps[k]] > temp; j -= gaps[k])
horses[j] = horses[j-gaps[k]];
horses[j] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gaps[] is an experimentally derived sequence for shell sort.
Take a look at the last entry in the wiki table for shell sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences

Wiki reference for this sequence:

https://oeis.org/A102549